# VisualStateManager WPF not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have designed a window exclusively in VS Blend 2017 designer without applying any changes to XAML code. I have created a StateGroup and a State and recorded changes on a Button. When trying to apply the state from code-behind, nothing happens.

Also I've seen the topics on the same question but unfortunately none worked for me!

Code-Behind:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "State1", false);
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_2017.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_2017"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MyStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="State1">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="button">
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFEA8686"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="button">
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFFF4848"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Margin="208.306,116.798,218.093,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26.065" Click="button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visual states should be defined in the `ControlTemplate` of the control:

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_2017.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window10" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MyStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="State1">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="button">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFEA8686"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="button">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFFF4848"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <AdornerDecorator>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Margin="208.306,116.798,218.093,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26.065" Click="button_Click"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </AdornerDecorator>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Template>
</Window>
```

That's where the `VisualStateManager` looks for them.

Comment: Thank you but nothing changed!

Comment: It certainly works just fine for me. Did you really copy the my XAML markup and pressed the Button?

Comment: I'm sorry now it works out! Do you know why the Designer is producing faulty code?

Comment: Well, it is simply not smart enough to handle all cases. After all, it is a designer :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should use GoToElementState instead of GoToState.

Please try this,

Add the name to the gird:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MyStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="State1">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="button">
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="button">
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Margin="208.306,116.798,218.093,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26.065" Click="button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and use it in code behind.

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this.MyGrid, "State1", false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , sorry abou that. I will provide you correct answer shortly.